# I have imported an project to eclipse wen i try to run the project i got one simple error am new to this so unable to rectify it

Tags: java, eclipse

Error 1:

> Description Resource Path Location Type The project was not built
>   since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for
>   java.util.Map$Entry. Fix the build path then try building this project
>   EmailSendingWebApp Unknown Java Problem

error 2 :

> Description Resource Path Location Type The type java.util.Map$Entry
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files EmailUtility.java /EmailSendingWebApp/src/net/codejava/email
>   line 29 Java Problem

This is my code:

```html
code 1 : package net.codejava.email;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 * A utility class for sending e-mail messages
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class EmailUtility {
 public static void sendEmail(String host, String port,
   final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
   String subject, String message) throws AddressException,
   MessagingException {

  // sets SMTP server properties
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
  properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

  // creates a new session with an authenticator
  Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
   public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
   }
  };

  Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

  // creates a new e-mail message
  Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
  InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
  msg.setSubject(subject);
  msg.setSentDate(new Date());
  msg.setText(message);

  // sends the e-mail
  Transport.send(msg);

 }
}



code 2 : 
package net.codejava.email;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * A servlet that takes message details from user and send it as a new e-mail
 * through an SMTP server.
 * 
 * @author www.codejava.net
 * 
 */
@WebServlet("/EmailSendingServlet")
public class EmailSendingServlet extends HttpServlet {
 private String host;
 private String port;
 private String user;
 private String pass;

 public void init() {
  // reads SMTP server setting from web.xml file
  ServletContext context = getServletContext();
  host = context.getInitParameter("host");
  port = context.getInitParameter("port");
  user = context.getInitParameter("user");
  pass = context.getInitParameter("pass");
 }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // reads form fields
  String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");
  String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
  String content = request.getParameter("content");

  String resultMessage = "";

  try {
   EmailUtility.sendEmail(host, port, user, pass, recipient, subject,
     content);
   resultMessage = "The e-mail was sent successfully";
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
   resultMessage = "There were an error: " + ex.getMessage();
  } finally {
   request.setAttribute("Message", resultMessage);
   getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp").forward(
     request, response);
  }
 }
}
```

I am new to eclipse so I don't know how to link these two files, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse can compile Java projects against different installed JREs. Unless care is taken, the project's reference to its JRE is not portable. Verify that your **Installed JREs** preference page is pointing to something valid, then edit the project's **Java Build Path** so that it's referring to a valid JRE.

http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/debug/ref-installed_jres.htm

http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm?cp=1_4_3_1